# Implementing Prim's algorithm in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I facing difficulties implementing prim's algorithm, my logic is quite wrong, this is what I got so far:

```
import Data.Array
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy, delete)

type Vertex = Int
type Weight = Int
type Graph  = Array Vertex [(Vertex, Weight)]
type Bounds = (Vertex, Vertex)
type Edge   = (Vertex, Vertex, Weight)

g1 = mkGraph (1, 4) [(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 10), (1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 10), (3, 4, 1)] -- 5
g2 = mkGraph (1, 5) [(1, 2, 15), (1, 3, 10), (2, 3, 1), (3, 4, 3), (2, 4, 5), (4, 5, 20)] -- 34

mkGraph :: Bounds -> [Edge] -> Graph
mkGraph bounds edges = accumArray (\xs x -> x:xs) [] bounds [ (x, (y, w)) | (x, y, w) <- edges]

--[(1,[(4,3),(3,10),(2,1)]),(2,[(4,10),(3,4)]),(3,[(4,1)]),(4,[])]
prim :: Graph -> Vertex -> [(Vertex, Weight)]
prim graph start = prim' (sortBy (compare `on` snd) (graph ! start)) [start] []
    where
        prim' [] _ mst = mst
        prim' (x:xs) visited mst
            | elem (fst x) visited = prim' xs visited mst
            | otherwise            = prim' (delete x $ sortBy (compare `on` snd) ((graph ! (fst x)) ++ xs)) ((fst x):visited) (x:mst)
```

My idea was, if I put every edge that is possible to reach from the vertice start (let's say that is 1) pick the minimum (in this case is the first element from that list, because it's sorted), pick it's first element from the tuple and use that as an index and also make all edges reachable from that vertice while adding the vertices reachable from the previous vertice too.

While doing this keeping track of the vertices visited, the problem is that if it reach the final vertice (it will be empty) then it will stop adding the edges and will use just the edges that was added already.

But this will not work either, because the way that I'm keeping tracking the visited vertices will skip something like [(1, 3, 10) (2, 3, 1)], because it will mark the vertice 3 as visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your `Graph` representation as an array is implicitly "directed", so you need to take your input undirected graph and tabulate edges **in both directions**:

```
mkGraph :: Bounds -> [Edge] -> Graph
mkGraph bounds edges = accumArray (\xs x -> x:xs) [] bounds 
    [(x, (y, w)) | (x', y', w) <- edges, (x, y) <- [(x', y'), (y', x')]]
```

Now, the invariant for the recursion is that in:

```
prim' outgoing visited mst
```

the argument `outgoing` is the list of `(vertex, weight)` pairs of all directed, *outgoing* arrows from anywhere in the `visited` set to some other `vertex` (possibly including some arrows pointing to `vertex`es already in the visited set).

At each recursive step, you skip any such outgoing arrows to vertexes you've already visited, and when you find an unvisited vertex with minimum weight, you add that edge to your `mst`, add the unvisited vertex to those `visited`, and augment the set of `outgoing` arrows with any arrows outgoing from the newly visited vertex.

(In your code, you `delete x`, though there's no technical need to do this, as it'll be filtered out as part of the "already visited" check.)

With the above change to `mkGraph`, your `prim` seems to work correctly on `g1`, `g2`, and the graph:

```
g3 = mkGraph (1,3) [(1,3,10), (2,3,1)]
```